# Retry button access methods in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, button, window

I have a button in a window that basically does a rerun through some code (retry button)

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnRetry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO retry function
        //MainWindow.Connect();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I basically want to use the connect method in my main window class. However I can't do that unless it's a public static. However, if I do change Connect() to a public static, all the controls in it require to be static. I'm trying to minimize the amount of static controls I have; can anybody please help with a retry method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to make `Window1.btnRetry` visible to the parent form

```
public MainWindow : Window
{
      private void ShowWindow1()
      {
          var window1 = new Window1();
          window1.btnRetry.Click += OnRetryClicked;
          window1.ShowDialog();
      }

      private void OnRetryClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // will be called when window1.btnRetry is clicked.
         // retry the connection.
         Connect();
      }
}
```

Comment: that worked! thanks! Now, whenever i press the retry button another window (same one) pops up without closing the previous one, would you know how to fix that?

Comment: In the click handler in `Window.btnRetry_Click`, call `Close()`. There can be more than one event handler per event. In general, make each class responsible for handling its own state.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do need to make the method public (or internal) so that `Window1` can use the method.  However, do not make it static.

Instead, accept an instance of `MainWindow` in the `Window1` constructor, and store it so that you can invoke the `Connect()` method on it later.

For example:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private MainWindow mainWindow;

    public Window1(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        if (mainWindow == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("mainWindow");
        }

        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnRetry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainWindow.Connect();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, if constructing the instance from inside of `MainWindow` change your constructor invocation from `new Window1()` to `new Window1(this)`.

Comment: isn't "this.mainWindow = mainWindow" assigning to the same thing?

Comment: No, it's not.  `this.mainWindow` refers to the object's field, while `mainWindow` refers to the parameter.